# Matching a precise number of characters in Regex

Tags: regex

Matching a precise number of characters {min,max}

File name (input_file) contains text as like below:

The Unix operating system was pioneered by Ken
Thompson and Dennis Ritchie at Bell Laboratories
in the late 1960s.

```
 grep '[A-Za-z]\{4,7\}' input_file
```

**Output:** grep command output, matched characters are marked in Bold letters for the references.

The **Unix** **operati**ng **system** was **pioneer**ed by Ken
**Thompso**n and **Dennis Ritchie** at **Bell** **Laboratories**
in the **late** 1960s.

After the execution of grep command,

first  word Unix:

Total number of word 4, so character Matching **Unix** with character long 4/4.

second word operating:

Total number of word 9, so character matching **operati**ng with 
character long 7/9.

Third word system:

Total number of word 6, so character matching **system** character long 6/6.

Fourth word **pioneer**ed

Total number of word 9, so character matching **pioneer**ed character long 7/9.

Fifth word **Thompso**n

Total number of word 8, so character matching**Thompso** character long 7/8.

Sixth word **Dennis**

Total number of word 6, so character matching **Dennis** character long 6/6.

Here my question is ? Word six having Dennis total number of character 6 but i mentioned {4,7} length long how it will matching entire word, i am not understating here.

Could you please some help me on this?

Comment: i don't really understand the question: `{4,7}` quantifies the matching elements to be between 4 and 7. 6 is inside the range, so why would it not match?

Comment: Try `grep -E '\b([a-zA-Z]{4}|[a-zA-Z]{7})\b'` if you plan to match whole words consisting of 4 or 7 letters.

Answer (score 2):

In the general case (when not using POSIX BRE): Don't *escape* the `{` and `}` characters.

```
[A-Za-z]{4,7}
```

This will match all continous strings of letters **between** 4 and 7 in length. The word 'Dennis' is six letter long and evidently a match.

The word 'Laboratories' is really two matches: 'Laborat' and 'ories'.

If what you really wanted is to match strings of length 4 **or** 7 then you can do this instead:

```
[A-Za-z]{4}|[A-Za-z]{7}
```

Comment: If you use `grep` without `-E`, it uses POSIX BRE flavor where one *must* escape the range quantifier. Your `grep '[A-Za-z]{4,7}'` will match any ASCII letter and the `{4,7}` literal text.